# Incorrect text in x.ticks( ) using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In one bar chart I am working on I have created parallel ticks to x Axis in order to give references to the viewer.
The problem is in text I have added. The text is ordered inversely as it should and I have no idea how to keep correct order.

I understand the problem is here:

```
  chart.selectAll("line")
        .data(y.ticks(4))
    .enter().append("line")
        .attr("x1", 60)
        .attr("x2", (barWidth + 50) * data.length)
        .attr("y1", y)
        .attr("y2", y)
        .style("stroke", "#ccc");

    chart.selectAll(".rule")
        .data(y.ticks(4))
    .enter().append("text")
        .attr("class", "rule")
        .attr("x", 30)
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(String);
```

But I don't know how to fix it.

[Here is the code in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fPxd/).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the y coordinates are counted from the top and not the bottom, so you need to reverse all the values. The updated jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7fPxd/1/); the relevant changes are below.

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(datum) { return datum.value; })])
      .rangeRound([height-20, 0]);
```

Reversed the values in `rangeRound` such that the lowest value is mapped to the top.

```
chart.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("svg:rect")
  .attr("x", function(datum, index) { return x(index); })
  .attr("y", function(datum) { return y(datum.value); })
  .attr("height", function(datum) { return height - y(datum.value); })
      ...
```

Changed how `y` and `height` are computed accordingly.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is working. I have to fix the top padding but the values are countered as I expected. Thanks a lot!